# How to check the session variable contains some specific value

Tags: php, session

I could retrieve my session variable which represents access locations as follows,

```
$_SESSION['access']
```

This session variable contains some strings as follows,

```
dummy1,dummy2,dummy3,dummy4
```

As an example `$_SESSION['access']` can be `dummy1` or  `dummy1,dummy2` or `dummy1,dummy2,dummy3` or `dummy2,dummy3,dummy4` likewise. Are there any method to find `contains` type of function?

```
Ex:
if($_SESSION['access']`.contains("dummy1")){
//do somthing, 
}
```

Or do I need to use mysql function to retrieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a method but function - as `string` is not an object in PHP.

The function is called [`str_contains`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php).

Use it like this on your example:

```php
if (str_contains($_SESSION['access'], "dummy1")) {
    //do somthing, 
}
```

The function is part of the language only recently (needs PHP 8).

For older PHP versions [`strstr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) was often used for this purpose (it also returns a substring of the original string, but only in case it is contained - which is exactly what we need here).

One would do so like this:

```php
if (strstr($_SESSION['access'], "dummy1")) {
    //do somthing, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit more verbose, but works:

```
if ( array_key_exists( "access", $_SESSION ) )  {
    $arrVals = explode( ',', $_SESSION["access"]) ;
    $key = "dummy1" ; // doesn't have to be hard-coded here, just for demo
    $b = array_search( $key, $arrVals ) ;
    if ( $b !== false ) {
        /// do your thing
        echo ( "found $key<br/>") ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please note that while more verbose than a string compare with strstr, this logic handles the case where two values share the same prefix, as in dummy1 and dummy12 -- a strstr will return hits on both dummy1 and dummy12.